# Jython with eclipse Java imports unresolved

Tags: java, python, eclipse, import, jython

I am new to Jython. Started developing with PyDev and eclipse. Created a PyDev project with a .py file. Added a jar to its classpath; but I am getting Unresolved Import for the Java classes. For the other classes which are a part of the .jar I added import is working fine (OmdWorkRepoSecure). But only for the other Java native imports like, RuntimeException or String, its saying Unresolved Import.

from org.omd.util import OmdWorkRepoSecure // working fine
...
from java.lang import RuntimeException // saying Unresolved Import

I think somewhere I am missing the Java related paths, but not sure where I can fix this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Weird. Are you trying to say that you can get user-defined Java imports to work but can't get standard library Java imports to work? Because standard Java libraries for me work no problem .. it's the user-defined Java files i'm trying to import which gives me the error

Comment: Anyway what have you tried? Did you add the Java classes to your Pydev project PYTHONPATH? Did you set your Java project as Pydev project so that you jython can call you Java class?